# How to make my count reset on for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
for count in range(1,numGames+1):
    print()
    try:
        print("Game", str(count))
        atBats = input("How many at bats did the player have? ")
        atBats = int(atBats)
        hits = input("How many hits did the player have? ")
        hits = int(hits)
        battingAverage = (hits / atBats)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Please enter a number")
        print(err)
```

Currently, when a letter is entered for `hits` or `atBats` for Game 1, it throws the exception and says `Please enter a number,` but it goes right to Game 2 without giving the user a chance to enter a new input for Game 1.

I would like to know if there is any way where it resets the game count when an exception is thrown.

Comment: **Tip:** use `hits = int(input("How many hits did the player have? "))`

Comment: thanks but our teacher wants us to use this format for now

Comment: So I call this just a tip ;)

Comment: **Tip 2**: Always use raw_input if you don't wanna mess with the scope

Comment: @PatrickBassut OP is on Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a while loop to run while the input isn't valid and breaks out when it is.

```
for count in range(1,numGames+1):
    print()
    while True:
        try:
            print("Game",str(count))
            atBats=input("How many at bats did the player have? ")
            atBats=int(atBats)
            hits=input("How many hits did the player have? ")
            hits=int(hits)
            battingAverage=hits/atBats
        except Exception as err:
            print("Please enter a number")
            print(err)
            continue
        break
```

Comment: by making the try blocks more modular, your feedback can be more contextual. Also, there is no point in running both the `for` and `while` loops. Even if you need to run a pre-specified number of games, it would be better to `while play and count < numGames + 1`. Finally, there is no need to have the cast to `int` in a separate call.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach and use a while loop instead, creating a variable called *i* and reseting it when the error happens:

```
numGames = 5 # This is an example, take your variable instead
i = 1
while i < numGames:
    print()
    try:
        print("Game",str(i))
        atBats=input("How many at bats did the player have? ")
        atBats=int(atBats)
        hits=input("How many hits did the player have? ")
        hits=int(hits)
        battingAverage=hits/atBats
        i = i + 1
    except Exception as err:
        print("Please enter a number")
        print(err)
        i = 1
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the count to reset completely, looks like he just wants to invalidate that loop

Comment: Ops, misinterpreted OP then. @chromano solution is the valid one then.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Try this:

```
count = 1
play = True # instead of the for loop use a while until you set it to false
while play:
    print "Game #%d" % count
    try:
        atBats = int(input("How many at bats did the player have?"))
    except Exception as err:
        print "You need to enter a number for at bats"
        continue # this will start the while loop over, missing counts += 1
    try:
        hits = int(input("How many hits did the player have?"))
    except Exception as err:
        print "You need to enter a number for hits"
        continue
    battingAverage = hits / atBats
    print "Your batting average is %d" % battingAverage
    count += 1
```